# Source control in IDE

Tags: svn, version-control

I've been having problems using SVN in ANY IDE that I try to use it in. It always give the same error:

> svn: E175002: unknown host

I've tried it in [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and [Zend Studio](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/) and all of them give me exactly the same error. I have tried with both the IP and normal address. I'm using [assembla](https://www.assembla.com/home) for my SVN hosting although I've also tried with with [beanstalkapp](http://beanstalkapp.com/) and get the same error. Both of these are `https://` so I've also tried using a normal `http://` SVN host with the same error.

The weird thing is Tortiose SVN on the same PC works fine? Ive looked all over the internet and cant find a solution.

PC Details:

- Windows 8 32 bit.
- All antivirus and firewall software turned off.

CLI client result of svn ls URL:

```
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://subversion.assem
bla.com/svn/ajacode'
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/ajacode': Could no
t resolve hostname `https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/ajacode': No such host is
known.
 (https://subversion.assembla.com)
```

Comment: Tried to open the url in a browser? Maybe it's _really_ wrong? :X

Comment: The URL in the browser opens up, asks for the username/password and then goes to repository.

Comment: Try in CLI-client `svn ls YOUR-URL`. You problem doesn't correlate to IDE at all

Comment: Updated question with CLI client result.

Comment: As shown - Could not resolve hostname ajacode.svn.beanstalkapp.com. 1. **Why** do you have it on assembla repo? 2. Why DNS-servers of your ISP can't resolve it?

Comment: This is clearly a network problem and has nothing to do with "Source control in IDE". The question title is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

It's network issue, related to DNS resolving.
For quick workaround, try to resolve your host manually by editing [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) of your OS
For example:

```
64.250.188.50 subversion.assembla.com  
50.31.156.75 ajacode.svn.beanstalkapp.com
```

Also contact to your ISP or network admin about this

Comment: didn't make any difference

Comment: try with CLI:  svn list --username %username% --password %password% https://64.250.188.50/svn/ajacode   and provide CLI result

Comment: also provide svn --version output

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to make just a comment not an answer... xD

Web Browser could be using web proxy, and the svn client couldn't reach hostname because there is no direct internet connection.